# Is Workflow the right choice for something this simple?

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation

I have a problem report system that needs to

1. Send out an email to a configured group
2. Call a webservice & pass on the problem report to another team

There is no Human interaction or waiting involved.

To me it looks like using a Workflow for something this simple is an overkill.

My architect thinks Workflow is the best choice here.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The days of avoiding workflow foundation because it is too heavy to do simple things are gone.  Workflow Foundation 4.0 and now 4.5 are both very lightweight compared to 3.5 and prior.  Creating simple workflows like what you described are simple to both create and execute, and you can execute from anywhere.

The calling of a web service is an out of the box activity and the send email is an activity you can get from the samples.  Throw them both in a custom workflow activity using the FlowChart activity and use the WorkflowInvoker class in a method somewhere to fire and forget about it.  Not only is your job done, but you have a bit of documentation in the form of a workflow diagram to show what is happening.

[WorkflowInvoker class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.workflowinvoker.aspx)

[The Workflow Way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd851337.aspx) - Article by David Chappell to help describe the advantages of WF 4.0+

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is very detailed & helpful. We have decided to give WF a shot.

Answer (score 0):

CAVEAT : My experience with WF is based on the product as it was in .NET 3.5

I would agree with you here that WF seems to be overkill in this scenario. I would go so far as to say that scenario you have highlighted doesnt really warrant any BPM / workflow tool as it is quite straightforward.

The only reason why your architect may be asking you to use it that I can think of would be

- He knows something that you dont regarding future requirements
- Consistency across the application

However, if the scenario is just what you describe, most BPM tools but especially WF would be a much bigger overhead than of any use as WF especially is quite resource intensive to use (*I hear the new version is much improved over what shipped in 3.5 though*)

Answer (score 0):

Workflow is best suited to long running processes -- it provides persistence and durability so that business processes can be resumed across long durations.

Your process sounds like it could be implemented in script or C# as a single method.